# How do you add an attribute to a django app python module?

Tags: python, django

Given a django app called mattermost which has a model called Channel we can do something like this.

```
import mattermost
for channel in Channel.objects.all():
    print(channel)
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this

```
import mattermost
mattermost.channels.list
```

I've tried adding channels.py with a def list(): function in the same folder as mattermost/**init**.py.

I'm getting the following error.

```
In [7]: reload(mattermost)
Out[7]: <module 'mattermost' from '/home/csmu/mipgen-django/mattermost/__init__.py'>

In [8]: mattermost.channels.list
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-d4715777f4f1> in <module>()
----> 1 mattermost.channels.list

AttributeError: module 'mattermost' has no attribute 'channels'
```

How do you add an attribute to a django app python module?

The contents of channels.py:

```
import mattermost

def list():
    for channel in mattermost.models.Channel.objects.all():
        print(channel)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`from mattermost import channels
print(channels.list())`

This resulted in:

```
    In [1]: import mattermost

    In [2]: mattermost.channels.list()
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-2-249466f32547> in <module>()
    ----> 1 mattermost.channels.list()

    AttributeError: module 'mattermost' has no attribute 'channels'

    In [3]: from mattermost import channels

    In [4]: mattermost.channels.list()
    list.stub

    In [5]:
```

which is close.

Comment: Any ideas on how to automatically do `from mattermost import channels`?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered you can do this by adding the following to mattermost/__init__py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, pkgutil
__all__ = list(module for _, module, _ in 
pkgutil.iter_modules([os.path.dirname(__file__)]))
```

then the following works

```
import mattermost
from mattermost import *
mattermost.channels.list()
```

which produces output for each mattermost channel.